# How to handle the deadlock/hang up in jdbc with oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, deadlock

I wrote a application which uses jdbc to insert records into table A. Now I found whenever I insert a record into table from other client and didn't commit. the my application will hang at the insert sql until I commit the change from other client.
How can I avoid this problem ? I don't want my application to wait until other client commit their changes.

Comment: how is it possible that committing the transaction for the insert from other clients takes so long? Are you in control of this clients? Can you show the code which creates the transaction, does the insert and commits?

Comment: other client means "SQLDEVELOPER", which I can insert a record, and never issue a "commit" command.

Comment: You might want to use different isolation level. Thous are described [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c21cnsis.htm). Make sure it wont break your data consistency.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm, as I am using oracle 11, I will refer to this. Do you have any suggest from your experience ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSERTs should not normally wait on each other.

One exception to that is when you try to insert the same (primary) key from two concurrent transactions:

- the first one to reach the INSERT will continue normally,
- but the second one will stall at its INSERT until the first one either commits (causing a key violation in the second one) or rolls back (allowing the second one to continue normally).

Interactions between UPDATE and INSERT or even DELETE and INSERT may also cause similar kind of stall.

You could always artificially trigger this kind of behavior from generic tools such as SQL Developer and I would not be too worried about that.

If, however, you have a bunch of client applications stalling each other for prolonged periods of time, you should try to either shorten the length of your transactions or redesign your database (e.g. by using SEQUENCE to guarantee automatic assignment of unique PK) and/or client logic so these kinds of "conflicts" are minimized.

Comment: Thanks,how can I try to shorten the length of your transactions ? in client applications or my application ?

Comment: Maybe you can "isolate" the operation that "stalls" other operations in its own, shorter transaction. Maybe you can reshuffle the operations within your existing transaction so the "stalling" operation is executed nearer the transaction end. Maybe you are doing some database-independent processing  that can be moved before or after transaction. Maybe you can redesign your database model so operations are "spread" over more tables. Etc, etc... You are the only one with enough domain-specific knowledge to know which of these approaches (if any) can be applied without disturbing the correctness.

Comment: Yes "client application" is your application.

Comment: Another way INSERTs can block each other is if you're using direct-path INSERTs: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/tables004.htm#ADMIN01509

Answer (score 1):

What Branko mentioned is 1 of the reasons. This's the mistake I did in debugging apps using Transactional query where I simply quit debugging after a insert query is executed without commit/rollback using oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver thin client.

**However**, what's not mentioned here is, if you happen to run a SQL Client Browser i.e SQL Developer to check your table or to verify your insert statement at the same time, they're also the culprit contributing to the freeze. In debugging mode, while stepping through the code (i.e statement.executeUpdate(); ) you will notice that your code seems waiting for server response indefinitely ... very long ... without giving exception. This happens if you perform previous uncommitted query again. And U'll find your SQL Browser connection is also affected.

It also depends on how you construct the query

```
i.e: 
insert into TB1(ID, Name) values (1, 'User1') x 2 times w/o commit --> freeze on 2nd time 
insert into TB1(ID, Name) values (SEQ.nextval, 'User1') x 2 times w/o commit --> OK, won freeze on 2nd time 
*where ID = auto number*
```

Solution:

Stop debugging/runtime server that manage the connection. Close / disconnect all your SQL browsers. Easiest way is close SQL Browser, restart eclipse/netbean IDE if U're unsure.

There're times you may need DBA rights to release(rollback/commit) those uncommitted transactions backlog. The RDBMS server is waiting for actions on those query upon the same col bfr moving to your next query.

Don use transactional query if not necessary by setting the Connection object:

```
<connection>.setAutoCommmit(true)
```